How to get the ScrollView from a ScrollController?
If you're only having a ScrollController instance, how do you get the ScrollView it is controlling?
First idea would be Scrollable.of(), but in this particular case the wanted ScrollView might be further up than the closest instance. And because both ScrollViews use the same axis, Scrollable.of(axis: ) won't work either.
Any ideas are welcome. Thank you.

I don't think you can do that but maybe this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollNotification-class.html would help?

Hi @psking, thanks for sharing this. ScrollNotification unfortunately won't work in this situation, because the receiver is at an Overlay, whereas the ScrollViews are at the Scaffolds widget tree - so I'm afraid the notifications won't bubble up. But thanks anyway!

I think about 2 approaches. None of them is ideal, in my opinion, but may be it can be a start for you to invent appropriate solution for ur case.

Use visitAncestorElements from the bottom of your widget tree. This method is kinda similar to Scrollable.of in terms that it will traverse widget tree also. But you decide when needed widget is reached.

Example (not 100% sure about syntax, but I think the idea is pretty clear):
ScrollView? findScrollView(BuildContext context, ScrollController controller) {
  ScrollView? result;
  context.visitAncestorElements((element) {
    if (element.widget is ScrollView) {
      final scrollView = element.widget as ScrollView;
      if (scrollView.controller == controller) {
        result = scrollView;
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  });
  return result;
}

Biggest downside – traverse is pretty heavy operation, and even documentation tells about it. So must be careful.

Create a GlobalKey object and use it as key of ScrollView. But of course, it will work only if you know which ScrollView you want to access in compile time(or, when writing a code). But if you situation is pretty static, say you have several ScrollViews, but you know exactly which one you want to access, you just need reference to it, it should work.

Something like this:
// Inside your widget or widget's state
final scrollViewKey = GlobalKey();

// somewhere inside build()
ScrollView(
  key: scrollViewKey,
  controller: yourScrollController,
)
...

// Somewhere in code, where you need your scrollView
final scrollView = scrollViewKey.currentWidget as ScrollView;

Hope this helps, good luck!

Thank you very much for sharing this. 'visitAncestorElements()' looks interesting. I'll have a closer look at it. Otherwise, workaround through GlobalKey will work for sure.
